# Generate generated folder when starting springboot netty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-webflux

[image]

I am studying spring webflux, but the generated folder is created when the server starts. Do you know why?

If you restart the server after deleting the generated folder, it will be created again.

The build.gradle file was configured as follows.

spring boot 2.2.7.RELEASE version and using jdk 8.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    restDocsVersion = "2.0.2.RELEASE"
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3"
  }

}

plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.2.7.RELEASE"
  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
  id "java"
  id "groovy"
  id "org.asciidoctor.convert" version "2.4.0"
}

ext {
  snippetsDir = file("build/generated-snippets")
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
  inputs.dir snippetsDir
  dependsOn test
}

bootJar {
  dependsOn asciidoctor
  
  from("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
    into "static/docs"
  }
  
  dependsOn "copyDocs"
}

task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
  from "${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5"
  into "src/main/resources/static/docs"
}

group = "com.example"

java {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}

build {
  dependsOn clean
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive"
  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
  annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
  }
  testImplementation "io.projectreactor:reactor-test"

  annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
  compile group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-core", version: "2.9.8"
  compile group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-annotations", version: "2.9.8"
  compile group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-databind", version: "2.9.8"

  compile group: "com.googlecode.json-simple", name: "json-simple", version: "1.1.1"

  asciidoctor "org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor:${restDocsVersion}"
  testCompile "org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-webtestclient:${restDocsVersion}"
  compile group: "org.codehaus.groovy", name: "groovy-all", version: "2.5.8"


}
```